# Indicating in groovy to use the value of textfield named 'A ' at a different position int the same gsp

Tags: grails, gsp

I have a gsp Customers.gsp. In it there is a search link on clicking which i have to call search action in controller, passing the value of a textfield named A, which is in the same Customers.gsp.What i tried is this:

**TextField:**

```
 <g:textField class="field" name="A"  id="A" />
```

This is the link on clicking which i need to get value of text field A

```
<g:link action="search" params="[Company:${A}]" class="submit add"><span><g:message   code="Search"/></span></g:link>
```

I tried ${A} and it causes error while rendering: "no signature of the method found..."

So what is the way in grails to do this instead of $(A) here?PLZ helppp...

Comment: I think you should use g:submitButton and g:form, otherwise if you want to use g:link U should pass params using js.

Comment: `<g:link` generates this link on server side, before user enters value into a text field

Comment: Thanks for the comments, i will try submitbutton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used submitButton inside form tag.This is because **the data in a text field will only be passed to the server if you submit a surrounding form (unless you use Javascript)**,and also as Igor Artamonov said **link tag generates the link on server side,before user enters value into the text field**.

Answer (score 0):

You may also be able to omit the ${} in the params argument like this:

```
<g:link action="search" params="[Company:A]" class="submit add"><span><g:message   code="Search"/></span></g:link>
```